# How to pass arguments to a script invoked by source command?

Tags: linux, bash

I am invoking a script through `source` command and want to pass arguments to the script.

I have checked `man source`, the bash returns:

> : [arguments]
>                 No effect; the command does nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing any  specified redirections.  A zero exit code is returned.
>
> source filename [arguments]
>                 Read  and  execute commands from filename in the current shell   environment and return the exit status of the last command executed from     filename.  If filename does not contain a slash, file names  in  PATH  are used   to find the directory containing filename.  The file searched for in PATH need   not be executable.  When bash is  not  in  posix  mode,  the  current  directory    is searched  if  no file is found in PATH.  If the sourcepath option to the shopt   builtin command is turned off, the PATH is not searched.  If any arguments are   supplied, they become the positional  parameters  when  filename  is  executed.     Otherwise  the  positional  parameters are unchanged.  The return status is the   status of the last command exited within the script (0 if no commands are executed), and false if filename is not found or cannot be read.

It has no examples, so I don't understand it .

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Create a file `test.sh` with the following contents:

```
echo "I was given $# argument(s):"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

and then source it from an interactive shell session:

```
$ source ./test.sh a 'b c'
I was given 2 argument(s):
a
b c
```

so you access the arguments just like you would do in a regular bash script, with `$@` or `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

For comparison, run it as a regular script:

```
$ bash ./test.sh a 'b c'
I was given 2 argument(s):
a
b c
```

Comment: script != bash :(. This will not work on POSIX compliant shells (dash).

Comment: The question is tagged `bash`; a POSIX-compliant answer isn't required.

Comment: While it was not required, the heads up was appreciated: Must of us lives in a mixed shell environment and it's good to know that this are not POSIX compliant, but BASH(/ZSH/KSH/...) only.

Comment: The question may be tagged bash, but for those of us who need to write POSIX shell scripts, it's already difficult enough to find non-bash answers. And, really, a (reasonable recent) bash isn't that ubiquitous, unfortunately (see MacOS Darwin). I really appreciate POSIX shell solutions when they are provided.

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on the (currently accepted) answer from redneb...

**TL;DR** Need to source a script with no positional arguments *within another script*? try `function DoSource() { source test.sh ; } ; DoSource` instead of just `source test.sh`.

### `source`ing a script with no arguments within another script

The excerpt from **Bash** manual in the question shows the details of how the positional parameters are assigned to the sourced script. In particular, *if the source command does not specify any argument*, it is assigned the ones from the calling environment.

A consequence is that it may be troublesome to `source` a script *passing no arguments* within another script.
For example, let's use redneb example as `test.sh`:

```sh
echo "I was given $# argument(s):"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

sourced within another script `userScript.sh`, which is e.g. the one-liner:

```sh
source test.sh
```

When running an example like above:

```
$ bash userScript.sh a 'b c'
I was given 2 argument(s):
a
b c
```

`test.sh` inherits `userScript.sh` positional arguments... which now is not what I want (if I did, I could have used `source test.sh "$@"`).

I have found the following to be a useful workaround: encapsulate the source command into a Bash function. The new `userScript.sh` looks like:

```sh
function DoSource() { source test.sh ; }
DoSource
```

reports:

```
$ bash userScript.sh a 'b c'
I was given 0 argument(s):
```

Note that specifying an empty argument (`source test.sh ''`) is not equivalent, since the empty argument would be passed to `test.sh`.

#### If the sourcing script is also expected to be sourced

If `userScript.sh` itself is supposed to be sourced, then one probably does not want to leave `DoSource()` around. In that case, the simple solution is self destruction:

```sh
function _userScript_sh_DoSource() { source test.sh ; unset "$FUNCNAME" ; }
_userScript_sh_DoSource
```

for one-time-only usage (function name has been chosen to reduce the chance of name conflicts); or a `unset _userScript_sh_DoSource` command can be places after `_userScript_sh_DoSource` is not needed any more.

#### Flexible variant for multiple use

A more complex variant of `DoSource()`:

```sh
function DoSource() { local ScriptName="$1" ; shift ; source "$ScriptName" ; }
DoSource test1.sh
DoSource test1.sh "$@"
DoSource test2.sh
```

can be used as a "drop-in" replacement for `source`, with the only difference being that when no positional argument is specified for the script to be sourced, `source` inherits them, while `DoSource` uses none.
Note however that `DoSource` is a function and as such behaves differently from `source` in other aspects (e.g. stack call, `FUNCNAME`, ...).

Answer (score 2):

Bourne shell and some other shells ignore the parameters passed to "." (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5024/passing-variables-to-a-bash-script-when-sourcing-it).

I can propose one workaround. Let imagine the script which you want to source looks like this:

```
$ cat ./setEnv 
export BRANCH=$0
export TARGET=$1
```

The usual way it does not work:

```
$ sh -c '. ./setEnv master linux; echo BRANCH=$BRANCH ; echo TARGET=$TARGET'
BRANCH=sh
TARGET=
```

But if you specify the parameters after the ' ' then they will belong to the parent shell that is they will be accessible in the script which you are sourcing:

```
$ sh -c '. ./setEnv; echo BRANCH=$BRANCH ; echo TARGET=$TARGET' master linux
BRANCH=master
TARGET=linux
```

I use this way when I need a oneline-command in Bourne shell which starts from ". ./setEnv" and continues with multiple commands separated with ; or &&.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled over another trap

test.sh

```
echo "I was given $# argument(s):"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
source test2.sh
```

test2.sh

```
echo "I was given $# argument(s):"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

now call

```
>bash test.sh a b
```

output:

```
I was given 2 argument(s):
a
b
I was given 2 argument(s):
a
b
```

This might be a problem if test2.sh evaluates arguments resp. argument count. To avoid this you can for example shift the args away.

test.sh

```
echo "I was given $# argument(s):"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
for arg in "$@"; do shift; done
source test2.sh
```

EDIT:

Just noticed https://stackoverflow.com/users/4633275/hamlet already covered this topic.

See also [Avoid command line arguments propagation when sourcing bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103034/avoid-command-line-arguments-propagation-when-sourcing-bash-script)