# Avoid command line arguments propagation when sourcing bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script `a.sh` that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $#
echo $1
```

and a script `b.sh` that looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source ./a.sh
```

If I call `./a.sh` I'm correctly getting 0 and an empty line as output. When calling `./a.sh blabla` I'm getting 1 and blabla as output.

However when I call `./b.sh blabla` I'm also getting 1 and blabla as output, even though no argument was passed to `a.sh` from within `b.sh`.

This seems to be related to the use of `source` (which I have to use since in my real use case, `a.sh` exports some variables). How can I avoid arguments from `b.sh` being propagated to `a.sh`? I thought about using `eval $(a.sh)` but this makes my `echo` statements in `a.sh` fail. I thought of using `shift` to consume the arguments from `b.sh` before calling `a.sh` but I don't necessarily know how many arguments there are.

Comment: It's not arguments being propagated from `b` to `a`. It's the code being sourced from `b` into `a`. That's the reason of existence of `source`. Otherwise, a standard execution in a subshell would be enough.

Comment: Then don't use `source`.
`#!/bin/bash
./a.sh
`

Comment: You do can shift before sourcing: `for arg in "$@"; do shift; done`

Comment: The reason I'm doing `source` is that I need variables exported in `a.sh` to be available afterward in `b.sh`.

Comment: So you basically want a.sh to change b.sh's environment, but also prevent a.sh from accessing b.sh's environment. How is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The root of the problem is an anomaly in how the `source` command works. From the [bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), in the "Shell Builtin Commands" section:

> . *filename* [*arguments*]
> source *filename* [*arguments*]
> [...] If any *arguments* are supplied, they become the positional parameters when *filename* is executed. Otherwise the positional parameters are unchanged.

...which means you can override the main script's arguments by supplying different arguments to the `source`d script, but you can't just *not pass* arguments to it.

Fortunately, there's a workaround; just `source` the script in a context where there are no arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
wrapperfunction() {
    source ./a.sh
}
wrapperfunction
```

Since no arguments are supplied to `wrapperfunction`, inside it the arg list is empty. Since `a.sh`'s commands are run in that context, the arg list is empty there as well. And variables assigned inside `a.sh` are available outside the function (unless they're declared as `local` or something similar).

(Note: I tested this in bash, zsh, dash, and ksh93, and it works in all of them -- well, except that dash doesn't have the `source` command, so you have to use `.` instead.)

Update: I realized you can write a generic wrapper function that allows you to specify a filename as an argument:

```
sourceWithoutArgs() {
    local fileToSource="$1"
    shift
    source "$fileToSource"
}
sourceWithoutArgs ./a.sh
```

The `shift` command removes the filename from the function's arg list, so it's empty when the file actually gets sourced. Well, unless you passed additional arguments to the function, in which case those *will* be in the arg list and will get passed on... so you can actually use this function to replace both the without-args and the with-args usage of `source`.

(This works in bash and zsh. If you want to use it in ksh, you have to remove `local`; and to use it in dash, replace `source` with `.`)

Answer (score 1):

You can even keep passing normal arguments using

```
source() {
    local f="${1}"; shift;
    builtin source "${f}" "${@}"
}
```

It is also possible to check from the sourced file what arguments have actually been given

```
# in x.bash, a file meant to be sourced
# fix `source` arguments
__ARGV=( "${@}" )
__shopts=$( shopt -p ) # save shopt
shopt -u extdebug
shopt -s extdebug # create BASH_ARGV
# no args have been given to `source x.bash`
if [[ ${BASH_ARGV[0]} == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]; then
  __ARGV=() # clear `${__ARGV[@]}`
fi
eval "${__shopts}" # restore shopt
unset __shopts
# Actual args are in ${__ARGV[@]}
```