# Why does 'source' behave differently from this script than from the terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment

I have two scripts, one of which I control (`myscript`), one of which I do not (I will call `source_issue.sh`). I am trying to use utilities in `myscript` that would usually be brought in by sourcing `source_issue.sh`. When I do this however, `source_issue.sh` is unable to run because the environment path it is generating is not correct.

**MVE:**

`source_issue.sh` (heavily stripped down from the full version I have to work with):

```
SETTINGS_FILE='source_issue.sh'
SCRIPT_LOC="./"

if [ $# != 0 ]; then
    echo "CASE 1"
    SCRIPT_LOC="$1"
else
    echo "CASE 2"
    SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI=$BASH_SOURCE
    SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI=${SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI%/*}
    if [ "$SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI" != "" ]; then
        if [ "$SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI" == "source_issue.sh" ]; then
            SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI="./"
        fi
        SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI=`readlink -f ${SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI}`
        if [ $? == 0 ]; then
            SCRIPT_LOC=${SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI}
        fi
    fi
    unset SCRIPT_LOC_TMP_UNI
fi

export PLNX=`readlink -f "${SCRIPT_LOC}"`

echo environment set to \'${PLNX}\'
#Would usually try to run something else from its directory using PLNX variable
```

And the MVE for `myscript` (also stripped down to show the issue):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd "$(dirname "$0")"

source $1
```

If I source `source_issue.sh` from the command line, it is as I expect, I am able to use the utilities it added to the path from the command line, have all the environment vars, etc:

```
<user@machine>:<cwd>$ source /home/<user>/Work/Experiments/random/source_issue.sh 
CASE 2
environment set to '/home/<user>/Work/Experiments/random'
```

However, if I do what I would think would be the exact same thing from a script, the environment is set in the `if` branch of `source _issue.sh` and incorrectly has the script name as part of its path/environment variable, breaking later parts of the script that use it to run utilities in the same folder:

```
<user@machine>:<cwd>$ ./myscript /home/<user>/Work/Experiments/random/source_issue.sh
CASE 1
environment set to '/home/<user>/Work/Experiments/random/source_issue.sh'
```

This also unsurprisingly ocurrs when I run `myscript from a desktop file (I can edit to add that but I think it is safe to say it is not the issue here).

I am sure this has something to do with environment variables/shell version/my lack of understanding what `source` does but I have tried a couple different possible solutions like using different shells in the shebang, running `source_issue.sh` directly instead of sourcing it in the script, and trying to figure out why it seems to interpret being `source`d from insude a script as having an argument passed to it, and for that matter, how it manages to generate the path it does from the `readlink` but have yet to fully grasp what is going on.

**The main problem/question I am having is**: I need to be able to source `source_issue.sh` from inside `myscript` and have it generate the correct path to its directory, as it would directly from the command line. I am not too worried about how this is accomplished, so long as it works and isnt too hacky.

Comment: CRIPT_LOC="./". It's probably the process working directory of myscript's invocation on the other script, try using full path of  source_issue.sh in myscript to source_issue.sh to invoke

Comment: It looks to me like the problem is that source_issue.sh is inheriting the argument list you passed to the parent script. This happens due to a quirk of the way `source` handles arguments. See if the solutions to ["Avoid command line arguments propagation when sourcing bash script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103034/avoid-command-line-arguments-propagation-when-sourcing-bash-script/61106037) work for you.

Comment: @GordonDavisson This is exactly what I was looking for, had no idea `source` had quirks like that but was able to solve the issue by using one of the wrapper functions supplied as an answer there. Thank you for your help here, if you want to post that as a simple answer I would accept it, otherwise I will write my own in a day or two and accept it for visibility. Thank you again!

Comment: @DouglasB It's better for the site's organization to mark this question as a duplicate, so anyone with a similar question that finds this one will get pointed to a single collection of answers. So just upvote the answer there that worked for you!